# List of Models binding not working in Asp MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having one problem with MVC. I want to use different models in the same view (to create one big form). I'm using the ViewModel method to gather my models inside.

ViewModel:

```
 public class EditByUserObjectsVM
    {
        public Person Person {set; get; }
        public List<EmergencyContact> EmergencyContacts {set; get; }

    }
```

I made my view like that (the Emergency Contacts side) :

```
<div class="tab-content">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.EmergencyContacts.Count(); i++)
    {

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab@(i + 1)" name="@(i + 1)">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].ID)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].PersonalMail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].PersonalMail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].PersonalMail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Adress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Adress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Adress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].PostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].PostalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].PostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Town, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Town, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Town, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Link, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Link, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmergencyContacts[i].Link, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    }        
    <ul class="pager wizard">
        <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Retour</a></li>
        <li class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Suivant</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The idea is to create a wizzard of 3 steps, where each step is an emergency contact form to fill.

At the end, there is 1 global submit button that send all the models data to my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditByUser(EditByUserObjectsVM editByUserObjectsVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    db.Entry(editByUserObjectsVM.Person).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    editByUserObjectsVM.EmergencyContacts[0].PersonSerial = editByUserObjectsVM.EmergencyContacts[1].PersonSerial = editByUserObjectsVM.EmergencyContacts[2].PersonSerial = editByUserObjectsVM.Person.Serial;
                    db.Entry(editByUserObjectsVM.EmergencyContacts[0]).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    db.Entry(editByUserObjectsVM.EmergencyContacts[1]).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    db.Entry(editByUserObjectsVM.EmergencyContacts[2]).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    var newException = new FormattedDbEntityValidationException(e);
                    throw newException;
                }
            }
            ViewBag.ResponsibleSerial = new SelectList(db.People, "Serial", "LastName", editByUserObjectsVM.Person.ResponsibleSerial);
            return View(editByUserObjectsVM.Person);
        }
```

When I'm clicking on submit button, I'm recieving in the controller my ViewModel Object, but the list of my emergency contacts contains only the first one filled in the wizzard ! the two others are null !

Can anyone tell me why please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form` should be outside the forloop.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="tab-content">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.EmergencyContacts.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab@(i + 1)" name="@(i + 1)">
                <fieldset>
                    <!-- ... -->
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        }  
        <ul class="pager wizard">
            <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Retour</a></li>
            <li class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Suivant</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Right now you're creating multiple forms. If you want to create one big form than you need to create just the one form with multiple tabs and fieldsets inside that one form.

Answer (score 1):

Likely, you're not carrying the data through. Each request stands on its own, so it must post all the data from previous requests *or* you must persist the previously posted data somehow, either storing it in a database or the session.

It's hard to tell from the code provided exactly how this is functioning. By the third contact, does the user then see 3 full sets of contact fields on screen? In other words, the first time through, there's only one set of field. The second time through, there's two sets with the first filled in, and finally the third time, there's two sets with filled data and one empty set ready to be filled by the user?

If that is the case, then I'd say this is pretty bad UI. Really it would be better to just forgo all the posting back and forth between the server and just render all three sets at once so the user can enter them all in one go.

If that's not the case, and each time, you're showing only a single set of fields, why do you have a loop there? You'll also again need to persist the other contact somehow between requests.